# Fields from imported android library not generated in R file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I need to integrate a certain SDK with my app, I added the .aar file in my gradle dependencies and I added the code they provided me.
The gradle build went with no special problems, but when I tried to start the SDK's activity the app crashed with the following exception:

```
12-07 16:28:09.991 16236-16236/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.positiveapps.clickins, PID: 16236
                                               java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field action_show_neura of type I in class Lcom/neura/standalonesdk/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.neura.standalonesdk.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.positiveapps.clickins-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
                                                   at com.neura.dashboard.R$id.<clinit>(R.java:995)
                                                   at com.neura.dashboard.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:59)
                                                   at com.neura.dashboard.activity.AppAuthenticationActivity.onCreate(AppAuthenticationActivity.java:26)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

After I went through the R files that are generated in my application I found out a significant amount of fields that exist in R.txt file in the aar are missing from the generated R.

I've tried building with and without proguard, updating gradle version, I cleaning and rebuilding the project, removing "build" directory manually, adding the aar as a module.
None of these seem to be the problem, the R file is still missing fields.

Thanks for any help, Ilia.

Answer (score 0):

Keep aar file in libs folder. ( as libname.aar )

then in app build.gradle specify following.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'libname', ext:'aar')
}
```

and click sync project with gradle files.

Then clean build the project.

Comment: can you please specify the SDK name !

Comment: The SDK is by company called Neura, it seems that it's not public yet.
I contacted them for help with this issue, it seems the problem is in the Proguad they compiled it with.

I'll update when I get a freshly compiled version from them.

Thank you!

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.neura.standalonesdk.R$string.common_google_play_services_api_unavailable_text”